# Reset GetLastError value

Tags: delphi, winapi

Delphi Xe.

in delphi help: "...Calling this function usually resets the operating system error state..."

How to reset a current error on 0? I.e. that GetLastError=0

Example:

```
Try
// There is an error
except
showmessage(inttostr(getlasterror)); // Ok, getlasterror<>0
end;
....
// no errors
....
// How to reset a current error on 0?
showmessage(inttostr(getlasterror)); // Again will be <> 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only be calling `GetLastError` *when there has actually been an error*. Some Windows API functions will reset the error to 0 on success, some won't. Either way, you should only interrogate the error state when you need to know the most recent error.

Note that there is a `SetLastError` method as well, but that doesn't help you; if you set the last error to 0, then of course `GetLastError` will return 0.

Comment: - There is no practical limitation to when call GetLastError. GetLastError is deterministic function.

Comment: @Downvoter Perhaps I was unclear, but I'm *not* saying that there's some magic going on with GetLastError. What I was saying was a) some functions will reset the error on success, while some won't (100% true, and in fact *you make that very point*) and b) there's not a good reason to want to ask about the last error unless a function has reported an error. The point of the method isn't to ask "did an error occur?" but rather to ask "why did my last API call return an error?" Given the OP's question, I think those are both valid and relevant points.

Comment: @Downvoter, the point was that unless you've been *told* there is an error, you shouldn't bother calling `GetLastError`. Don't use it to *detect* whether there was an error. That is, Gu's intended use case is flawed. Even if there really weren't any errors, there's no guarantee that `GetLastError` will return 0.

Comment: @dlev, @Rob Kennedy, i disagree, given that callee sets extended error info and returns basic error info, caller might stick to extended only error checking (this might lead to improvements in code readability). To convince me otherwise, callee must return TRUE, but **not** use SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS) beforehand.

Comment: @Downvoter, `GetLastError` documentation makes it clear: "Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they fail. However, some functions also set the last-error code when they succeed. If the function is not documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set; some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do not." Unless a function is *documented* to set the code on success, you shouldn't assume so, and you cannot use it to *detect* errors.

Comment: The comment about calling `GetLastError` only if there has actually been an error is invalid, because some Windows calls set the last error to a nonzero value _even if the function succeeds_, for example `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if you use CreateFile on an existing file.  The behavior is different for each API call you use, so you need to understand what each function does to the last error and act accordingly.

Comment: Note that there are some functions, such as `CreateFileMappingA()` which may set the last error without otherwise indicating a failure. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga#return-value

Answer (score 5):

It's actually a Win32 call (not Delphi per se).

You can clear it with "SetLastError ()".

Here's the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of low quality documentation. `GetLastError` WinAPI function will retain its return value until next call of `SetLastError` so repeatedly invoking will have no effect.

```
SetLastError(42);
for I := 1 to 100 do
  Assert(GetLastError() = 42); // all of those assertions evaluates to True
```

Also, in Delphi documentation GetLastError has been misplaced into exception handling routines; this is wrong too, these error handling mechanisms are unrelated to each other.

On that silly "usually" word in the reference: It happens because function used to output GetLastError return value invokes SetLastError. Eg:

```
  SetLastError(42);
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('GetLastError() = %d', [GetLastError()]))); // 42
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('GetLastError() = %d', [GetLastError()]))); // 0! (ERROR_SUCCESS set by the previous OutputDebugString call)
```